# Java Tic Tac Toe GUI

Tags: java, swing, tic-tac-toe

The code works fine but problem is that i want 3 columns and three rows.. But output shows 6 columns instead of three rows and three columns

Here is a code in which problem appears..
Here is a main class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import games.board.Board;
import games.board.Cell;
import games.board.Mark;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;



public class TicTacToeGUIGame extends JFrame  {

/**
 * @param args
 */
private Board gb;
private int turn;
private void takeTurn(Cell c) {
    Mark curMark = (turn++ % 2 == 0)? Mark.NOUGHT
    : Mark.CROSS;
    gb.setCell(curMark, c.getRow(), c.getColumn());
    }
private TicTacToeGUIGame() {
    gb = new Board(3, 3, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    Cell c = (Cell) ae.getSource();
    takeTurn(c);
    }
    });
    this.add(gb);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("TIC-TAC-TOE");
    this.setSize(300, 300);
    this.setVisible(true);
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable () {
        public void run() { new TicTacToeGUIGame(); }
        });

}

}
```

Here is a board class:

```
package games.board;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Board extends JPanel {
private Cell[][] cells;
public Board(int rows, int columns) {
cells = new Cell[rows][columns];
for( int r = 0; r < cells[0].length; r++ ) {
for (int c = 0; c < cells[1].length; c++) {
cells[r][c] = new Cell(r,c);
}
}
}
public Board(int rows, int columns, ActionListener ah) {
    cells = new Cell[rows][columns];
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    for( int r = 0; r < cells.length; r++ ) {
    for (int c = 0; c < cells[r].length; c++) {
    cells[r][c] = new Cell(r,c);
    this.add(cells[r][c]);
    cells[r][c].addActionListener(ah);
    }
    }
    }
public void setCell(Mark mark, int row, int column) throws
IllegalArgumentException {
if (cells[row][column].getContent() == Mark.EMPTY)
cells[row][column].setContent(mark);
else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Player already there!");
}
public Cell getCell(int row, int column) {
return cells[row][column];
}
public String toString() {
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
for( int r = 0; r < cells.length; r++ ) {
str.append("|"); 


for (int c = 0; c < cells[r].length; c++) {
switch(cells[r][c].getContent()) {
case NOUGHT:
    str.append("O");
    break;
    case CROSS:
    str.append("X");
    break;
    case YELLOW:
    str.append("Y");
    break;
    case RED:
    str.append("R");
    break;
    case BLUE:
    str.append("B");
    break;
    case GREEN:
    str.append("G");
    break;
    case MAGENTA:
    str.append("M");
    break;
    case ORANGE:
    str.append("M");
    break;
    default: //Empty
    str.append("");
    }
    str.append("|");
    }
    str.append("\n");
    }
    return str.toString();

}

}
```

Comment: That is a LOT of code. You'd get help much faster if you edited your code and only included the parts that were relevant to the question. For example, none of the three enums are relevant.

Comment: @user2694776 Way to accept mine and then unaccept a few seconds later. ;) Haha. Come on man that guys has 90k rep, he don't need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i want 3 columns and three rows.. But output shows 6 columns

You need to specify proper parameters to the GridLayout:

```
this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3));
```

This will tell the grid to contain 3 columns. The number of rows will depend on the number of components you add.

Answer (score 1):

Change in your Board class:

```
for( int r = 0; r < cells[0].length; r++ ) {
    for (int c = 0; c < cells[1].length; c++) {
      cells[r][c] = new Cell(r,c);
   }
 }
```

To

```
for( int r = 0; r < cells[0].length; r++ ) {
    for (int c = 0; c < cells[r].length; c++) {
      cells[r][c] = new Cell(r,c);
   }
 }
```

Comment: http://i.qkme.me/3vjgab.jpg Newlines & whitespace will help make your code more clear. It'll help compare to the original, and it'll make it easier to read.

Comment: @RyanAmos I once wrote a whole program on one line for the fun of it. `public class example { public static void main(String args[]) { System.out.println("hahaha"); } }` - Fairly difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it! @DummyCode That's mostly boilerplate code, so it's easy to read. Nested for loops start to get less boilerplate-y and hence more difficult to read without whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

> I want 3 columns and three rows... But output shows 6 columns

Use, `this.setLayout(new GridLayout(nRows, nColumns));`

Change `nRows` and `nColumns` accordingly to how many columns and rows you want, ie, if you wanted a `20x20` game you would use, `this.setLayout(new GridLayout(20, 20));`